# Suggestions needed to replace relay on this circuit

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, solid-state-relay, circuit-design

[image]I am designing this circuit for testing purpose to test the following conditions.

1.When +12V is applied to the test circuit,my Circuit B should be activated for 2ms and trip open.CKT B is already designed and working fine.During this condition,my CKT A should be inactive.
2.When no power is applied ,my CKT A should be activated.

I am using Normally closed relay in the place of switch(SW), so that my CKT A is always on and inactive when +12V is applied.The minimum response time of the relay I found was approximately 0.5ms.I want to reduce this response time as it will have an impact on CKT B activation time.

Is there any option to use any other switching device to satisfy this condition.

Comment: FETs will work much faster than relays, but it is not clear what exactly you want. What generates the 2 ms right now ?

Comment: How much current does circuit A draw when its active and how much "extra" resistance can be tolerated in series with circuit A before it fails to perform as you would want?

Comment: Mechanical relay will be far too slow.

Comment: @Andyaka: Basically I want my ckt A to be active when there is no +12V applied.Circuit A draw current of 10-20mA  from constant current source to measure the resistance.

Comment: You said that Ckt A draws 10-20 ma.  If it is only on when +12v is off (i.e. normally closed NC contact), where is the current source for Ckt A coming from (since you have it connected to the +12V line and nothing else)? Seems like Ckt A is never really connected to +12V but something else.   Is there more to the circuit than you are showing?

Comment: @tcrosley: Yes.Ckt A draws 10-20mA through the +12V line from the driver IC.The driver IC switches the input source based on the function.During diagnostic mode,the driver IC supplied constant current.During operation mode,it supplies +12V.So I don't want my CKT A to be enable during operation mode of Circuit B

Comment: when the +12v is off, do you still have other voltages like +5V available?

Comment: Yes.I have secondary supply of +5V to power other parts of the circuits

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need solid state relays and such; they are terribly expensive, at least $35 to get one with a low on-state resistance, and the best turn on/turn off times are in the order of 50-100 µs, not all that better than what you are using now.  Instead, you should be able to just use a N-channel FET as a low-side switch.  The [IPB009N03L](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/IPB009N03L_rev1.0.pdf?folderId=db3a3043156fd5730115c7d50620107c&fileId=db3a30431689f4420116d426b6770ca3) has a *very* low R\$_{DS(on)max}\$ of 0.95 mΩ, a turn-on delay + rise time of 50 ns, and a turn off delay + fall time of 125 ns.  It is designed to work with a logic level input since it has a minimum V\$_{GS}\$ of 2.2V.  It is available at [Digi-Key for $2.87](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IPB009N03L%20G/IPB009N03L%20GCT-ND/2231116).

The main disadvantage of a low-side switch is the switched circuit is no longer connected directly to ground. However with such a low R\$_{DS(on)max}\$, and currents under 20 mA, it shouldn't matter.

But if you must use a high-side switch, you could use the P-channel [IPB180P04P4L-02](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPB180P04P4L_02-DS-v01_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30432f69f146012f7845736e2e49&ack=t).  It also has a low R\$_{DS(on)max}\$ of 2.4 mΩ, a turn-on delay + rise time of 50 ns, and a turn off delay + fall time of 265 ns.  It has a minimum V\$_{GS}\$ of -2.2V.  It is available at [Digi-Key for $2.20](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IPB180P04P4L02ATMA1/IPB180P04P4L02ATMA1CT-ND/5413742).